# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar este proyecto de Netbeans, o no se puede hacer nada?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Ocurre que el día de hoy por algún motivo NetBeans no me abría, busqué un tutorial en Youtube y lo que me decía es que debía eliminar la carpeta "Netbeans" de disco local C>usuarios>administrador>AppData. Al eliminarla (hice una copia de seguridad, por si acaso) volvió a abrir NetBeans, aunque perdiendo algunas configuraciones, pero lo peor es que al abrir un proyecto importante que tenía me doy cuenta que el código de una clase está en blanco y no sé por qué. Así se ve en Netbeans Projects, donde debería verse el código de mi clase, no hay absolutamente nada pero puedo seleccionar como si estuviera invisible. Es el único código que se perdió porque entro a los demás y están intactos, pero no entiendo por qué justo este o si tuvo algo que ver la eliminación de la carpeta. Si existe alguna solución le agradeceré con el alma a quien me la haga saber. Gracias de antemano. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando trato de abrir el .jar de la carpeta "dist" me sale que está corrupto o inválido.

Esta es la carpeta que originalmente eliminé (no hallé dentro nada relevante, sospecho que no es por esto sino por algún error de compilación, pero no sé si un error de compilación puede arruinar una clase particular de un proyecto como en este caso):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto, las "configuraciones" que perdí cuando pude volver a abrir el Netbeans en realidad es que los proyectos que tenía abiertos (en las ventanas) ya no estaban y pues, tuve que abrirlos de nuevo, pero eso es todo: todo igual excepto la clase Juego que estaba arruinada.

Probé cambiando la extensión del .java a otros como word o .rtf y pegando el código invisible en varias partes y sigue sin aparecer. Es bastante extraño. No encontré información en internet sobre algo similar.

Comment: Hola John, con la poca info que nos das, es muy difícil atinar una respuesta, has intentado restaurar la copia de seguridad que hiciste y buscar en el explorador el archivo?, has probado copiar y pegar en otro archivo el código invisible?, existe la posibilidad de que hayas creado la clase faltante de una sola tacada,  y no hayas guardado?.

Comment: @Marce Si, lo primero que hice fue tomar la copia de seguridad de la carpeta esa "Netbeans" y volver a ponerla donde estaba, pero el código seguía sin aparecer, aunque realmente creo que en esa carpeta no hay nada relevante (busco dentro el archivo y no está) El código invisible si lo pegue en varias partes, hasta le cambié el formato y sigue invisible. Sobre esa última posibilidad no lo creo ya que tenía el proyecto guardado desde hace días, y siempre guardo cuando hago una modificación significativa.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre, es hagas una reparación de disco, si tenés un error puede verse reflejado de esa manera, no  creo que quede bien, pero tal vez recuperes una parte, otra idea ingenua sería cambiar la extensión a "txt", solo para probar.